# STS / Grails: Workspace dependency resolution

Tags: grails, dependency-management, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

My environment is STS 2.8.0-M2 with Grails 1.3.7. I have a Grails project and a plain Java/Maven project in my workspace.

I am used to M2Eclipse workspace dependency resolution for plain Java/Maven projects and I'd love to see something similar working with Grails. According to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7%20Dependency%20Resolution) it appears like Maven dependencies can only be pulled from a repository or a flat directory but NOT from another plain Java/Maven project in the same workspace. As far as I know, that's a feature coming from M2Eclipse, but enabling this one on the Grails project just causes STS to crash and I assume that it would still conflict with Grails even if I would use the Grails Maven plugin.

Do you guys have any advice or practical experience how to enable workspace dependency resolution with Grails in STS 2.8? I want to avoid having to rebuild a dependent project during development over and over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Beta/UAT releases I use artifactory to deploy my jars and grails picks up from the local artifactory with the mavenRepo variable in BuildConfig.groovy pointing to the local artifactory.
eg

```
mavenRepo "http://maya:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local/"
```

Development environment:

1)For plugins I use the line

```
grails.plugin.location.'plugin-name'="../PluginProject"
```

2) For normal java project I reference it directly using the build properties of the java project.

BuildConfig.groovy fulfills all my requirements and I never used maven in grails projects

Comment: Ganesh, sorry for not getting back to this reply earlier. This still implicates that I need to Maven build the dependency first. What I want is that dependent projects in the same workspace don't need to be built explicitly but are part of the Grails project classpath through the dynamically compiled output in the Eclipse target directory. (I could add these target directories manually indeed but I was hoping there was an "official" way.)

Comment: You don't need to add the "target directories" manually. You can add an entry in the Java Build Path setting in the grails project to point to the plain Java project. This is the "official" way. Or have I misunderstood the question and you want to add all java projects in the same workspace automatically to the grails build path?